# Ember : Deciding Routes

Tags: ember.js, routes

I have an application to build. This is the workflow :

```
Types ==>> Categories ==>> Subcategories ==>> Products ==>> Product
```

`product` route will be a single item view, all the others will be grids displaying data corresponding to the selected parent.
This is what I have thought of :

```
this.resource('products', function(){
    this.resource('types', function(){
        this.resource('type', {path: ':type'}, function(){
            this.resource('categories', function(){
                this.resource('category', {path: ':cat'}, function(){
                    this.resource('subs', function(){
                        this.resource('sub', {path: ':sub'}, function(){
                            this.route('productlist');                         
                            this.route('product', {path: ':pid'});
.
.
.
```

But I am not sure if this is the right way, given that the product should render in its own template. What should be done differently? Is this implementation correct logically?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should only need to create nested routes, if the UI is nested. If the routes UI are separate pages and you just need the url to look nested, just modifiy the path property in the routes.

Comment: @blessenm is right. The blind rule works well for almost all cases.  
http://ugisozols.com/blog/2013/11/05/understanding-nesting-in-emberjs/

Comment: @blessenm Thanks. I have accepted your advice. I have removed all nesting now, my application is better without it. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @selvagsz Quite true. That article is a good read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need to create nested routes, if the UI is nested. If the routes UI are separate pages and you just need the url to look nested, just modifiy the path property in the routes.

```
this.route('images');
this.route('image', {path: 'images/:image_id'})
```